# Will the UK be able to witness the tetrad in April 2014?

Tags: lunar-eclipse

I live in the UK and am aged 15. I have become extremely interested in astronomy, astrophysics, the lot. Basically I have never seen a tetrad and believe this will be my first time - at least understanding what it is. I'm hoping it will be possible and if so where will it be seen in the sky? As in North, South etc. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to edit the question, changing August to April (there isn't a lunar eclipse in August)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is great that you have an interest in astronomy.

Unfortunately, the UK will be on the wrong side of the Earth to see the lunar eclipse on April 15. If you you want to experiment with various places on earth that will see it, and what they will see, get a planetarium application like Stellarium or SkySafari or TheSkyX.

A lunar eclipse is always easy to spot - it is where the full moon is. Also, because it is the result of the Earth getting in the way of the Sun shining on the Moon, it is always after the sun sets and after the full moon rises in the East. That is, if you're going to be in a place to see the whole sequence, not just a part of it.

Just so you know, the tetrad is not one but a series of lunar eclipses over 2 years, this is just [the first lunar eclipse in the series](http://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/OH/OH2014.html#LE2014Apr15T). The last tetrad was 2003-2004, so you were around, but probably not paying as much attention at that time :-)

Unfortunately, Cambridge UK will not see any of the first 3 eclipses in this tetrad. However the 28 Sept 2015 eclipse will be visible from that location.

Incidentally, one of the better places to see this lunar eclipse will be Easter Island (Rapa Nui) which will see the whole eclipse, and with the totality occuring high in the sky, near the meridian. Also, not much light pollution.

Comment: Thanks, I have recently got a freelance job and am saving up to visit a place that will allow me to experience the eclipse later this year - I think around September time. Is it worth my money to visit a country, with a telescope, DSLR, etc and photograph it? It seems really interesting, however I'm not sure it is worth spending several hundreds of pounds on that, when the money could eventually fund my university fees. Also, if I were to go what telescope type would be recommended, I am getting a Newtonian Reflector, however I am not sure if this will work well with a lunar eclipse.

Comment: Also, I am ever so interested in nebulae. hence why i am getting a Newtonian Reflector. I have downloaded Stellarium, however I can't look carefully at nebulae. I have Deep Space Objects turned on, yet when I zoom in on a nebula it is just blank. Is there a certain option to allow me to see nebulae.

Comment: If you take a special trip somewhere to see an astronomical event, especially if you meet up with local astronomers, I am sure you will have a memorable time. You will have to judge if that is money better spent on equipment or education. Almost any telescope will help you get a better look at the moon during a lunar eclipse, a newt will be fine. Stellarium may not have an image for every nebulae, but it will tell you where to look and you'll be able to find it in relation to other nearby objects.

Comment: The lunar eclipse later in 2014 is early on Oct 8. Anchorage, Alaska is probably a good place to see it.

Comment: I've gotten reasonable images of a lunar eclipse using a DLSR and a 300mm lens.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, I just wanted to make sure 100% that there is no possible way of viewing the eclipse from my location. It is rather irritable when it's something of real interest to me and I wont have the chance to see it.

Comment: Why don't you watch the live telescope feed and commentary/discussion with astronomers on the slooh.com site? http://events.slooh.com/stadium/total-lunar-eclipse-arizona-april-15-2014

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13892/discussion-between-jeremy-and-harry-kitchener)